Line break React
I'm very new to coding. I have looked over MDN, WJ(something). I can't figure out how to put a line break
         return market.outcomes.map(
                                  ({ name, price, point }) => {
                                    let sbTemp = "";

                                    if (name === "Over") {
                                      sbTemp = "o";
                                    } else if (name === "Under") {
                                      sbTemp = "u";
                                    }

                                    if (point && point !== "price") {
                                      sbTemp += `${point}`;
                                    }
                                    sbTemp += price;

                                    return <td>{sbTemp}</td>;
                                  }
                                );
                              })}
                            </tr>

Like i said I tried to to use MDN, WJ3. <br>, \n. not understanding

In HTML/JSX the <br/> would work. It's unclear where you're trying to add it. Please [edit] your question with more detail on what you're trying to do, and better yet include your failed attempts

The question is misleading, you need to correct it. The problem lies with the fact that  is an inline-block element. Meaning, when we write
<td>item 1</td>
<td>item 2</td>
<td>item 3</td>

This won't add a line break for every item, everything will be in one line.
item 1 item 2 item 3

So, I am assuming you are trying to print a bunch of values in a cell. So, instead of
<td></td>

you can use something like
<p></p>.

or in the td tag itself, add a style property of
display: block;

I think this will do, but in case if this is not what you want. Feel free to comment on it.
